# Issues with JavaScript and onclickEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm creating a web site and for login and Subscribe I went for jquery.avgrund ( the PopIn) ...

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- CSS,JS ... -->

<script>


function myFunction() {

$('.tab a').on('click', function (ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

target = $(this).attr('href');
$('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
$(target).fadeIn(600);

});

return false;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>


<script src="js/jquery.avgrund.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#show').avgrund({
            showClose: true,
            showCloseText: 'close',
            onBlurContainer: '.container',
            template:


        '<br>'+
        '<ul class="tab-group">'+
        '<li class="tab active">'+
        '<a href="#signup" id="inscriptionMenu" onclick="return myFunction()">Inscription</a>'+'</li>'+
        '<li class="tab">'+'<a id="loginMenu" href="#login" onclick="return myFunction()">Log In</a>'+'</li>'+
        '</ul>'+   


       '<div class="tab-content">'+
        '<div id="signup">'+    

            '<div class="field-wrap">'+
           '<br>'+'<br>'+
           '<h1>Inscription</h1>'+'<br>'+
'<label class="label2">Email Address<span class="req">*</span>'+'</label>'+
'<br>'+'<br>'+'<input type="email" required="" autocomplete="off" class="input1">'  +
          '</div>' +

'<div class="field-wrap">'+
'<label class="label2">Password<span class="req">*</span>'+'</label>'+
'<br>'+ '<br>'+'<input type="password" required="" autocomplete="off" class="input1">'  +
          '</div>'+'<br>'+
  '<input type="button" value="s\'inscrire" class="buttonlogin" >'+'<br>' +'<br>'
  +'<h3>-- OU --</h3>'+'<br>'+

  '<input type="button" class="buttonfacebook" style=" background-image: url(images/facebook.png); ">'+
 '</div>'+

 '<div id="login" hidden=true>'+   
          '<h1>Welcome Back!</h1>'+
   '</div>'+
 '</div>'




 }); 

    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

**The Result is not bad:**

[image]

[image]

This looks nice but I have a small problem. The active section on start is *"Inscription"* but when I try to move to the login section it seems that the *onclick* event is not responding from the first time. I have to click twice on the link "*LogIn*" to make it work.

I thought that the *Onclick* was not responding for the first time but with a simple alert message it is responding but the changes are not applied... I have to click twice and this only the first time ...

To be more exact : 1) I click to show the dialog box - Pop-in 
                   2) I click twice on *Login* to make it work
                   3) it works fine and I can go from *Inscription* to *Login* and 
                      vice versa normally

The Problem is why do I have to click twice to make it work?

Also I noticed that when I show this Pop in and than click on the active tab which is by default "*Inscription*" the problem is gone and it works fine! 
It seems that by clicking on "*Inscription*" I'm changing something but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. Remove `onClick` attribute from code. What was happening with the first and second click:

**The first click was enabling the function binding and from the second click the event handler stated working.**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.tab a', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

        target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
        $(target).fadeIn(600);

    });
</script>
```

Change `<a href="#signup" id="inscriptionMenu" onclick="return myFunction()">Inscription</a>` to `<a href="#signup" id="inscriptionMenu">Inscription</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Do not put the following code in a function but rather in DOM ready. Since the code is used to set up an click event listener, when you put it in a function, it means that the event listener **will not be set up until the function runs at least once**. *The other problem is that every click will set up a new event listener and you will have the click handler firing as many times as the number of previous clicks.*

```
$('.tab a').on('click', fn);
```

Your set up should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab a').on('click', fn);
    //other code
});
```

This way the event listener gets set up as soon as the DOM is ready. If any of the `a` elements are created after DOM ready then use this version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //other code, including code adding a elements
    $('.tab a').on('click', fn);
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.tab a', fn);
    //other code, including code adding a elements
});
```